# unmelting a pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataform, dataframe

I melted a pandas dataframe for plotting use with ggplot (which often requires long form of dataframes), as follows:

```
test = pandas.melt(iris, id_vars=["Name"], value_vars=["SepalLength", "SepalWidth"])
```

This keeps the `Name` field of the iris dataset in the index, but transforms the columns `SepalLength` and `SepalWidth` into long form:

```
test.ix[0:10]
Out:
           Name     variable  value
0   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.1
1   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.9
2   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.7
3   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.6
4   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.0
5   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.4
6   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.6
7   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.0
8   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.4
9   Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.9
10  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.4
```

How can I "unmelt" this dataframe back? I want the `Name` column to be kept, but the values of `variable` field to be transformed into separate columns. The `Name` field is not unique, so I don't think it can be used as an index. My impression was that `pivot` is the right function to do this but it is not right:

```
test.pivot(columns="variable", values="value")
KeyError: u'no item named '
```

How could I do this? Also, could I unmelt dataframes where there are multiple columns that are in long form, i.e. multiple columns in `test` that are like the `variable` column above? It would mean that the `columns` will have to accept a list of columns, not a single value, it seems. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this situation is ambiguous since the `test` dataframe doesn't have an index that identifies each unique row. If `melt` simply stacked the rows with `value_vars` SepalLength and SepalWidth, then you can manually create an index to pivot on; and it looks like the result ends up the same as the original:

```
In [15]: test['index'] = range(len(test) / 2) * 2
In [16]: test[:10]
Out[16]: 
          Name     variable  value  index
0  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.1      0
1  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.9      1
2  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.7      2
3  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.6      3
4  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.0      4
5  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.4      5
6  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.6      6
7  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    5.0      7
8  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.4      8
9  Iris-setosa  SepalLength    4.9      9

In [17]: test[-10:]
Out[17]: 
               Name    variable  value  index
290  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.1    140
291  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.1    141
292  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    2.7    142
293  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.2    143
294  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.3    144
295  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.0    145
296  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    2.5    146
297  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.0    147
298  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.4    148
299  Iris-virginica  SepalWidth    3.0    149

In [18]: df = test.pivot(index='index', columns='variable', values='value')
In [19]: df['Name'] = test['Name']
In [20]: df[:10]
Out[20]: 
variable  SepalLength  SepalWidth         Name
index                                         
0                 5.1         3.5  Iris-setosa
1                 4.9         3.0  Iris-setosa
2                 4.7         3.2  Iris-setosa
3                 4.6         3.1  Iris-setosa
4                 5.0         3.6  Iris-setosa
5                 5.4         3.9  Iris-setosa
6                 4.6         3.4  Iris-setosa
7                 5.0         3.4  Iris-setosa
8                 4.4         2.9  Iris-setosa
9                 4.9         3.1  Iris-setosa

In [21]: (iris[["SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "Name"]] == df[["SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "Name"]]).all()
Out[21]: 
SepalLength    True
SepalWidth     True
Name           True
```

Comment: I'm confused about your `index` column. First, doesn't test already have a unique index that identifies each row, i.e. the default index? Also, what is the purpose of dividing by 2 before taking the range and then multiplying by two? Why can't you do: `test['index'] = list(test.index)` or something like that to create an arbitrary unique index for each row?

Comment: `len(iris) == 150, len(test) == 300`. The original index on `test` has a unique value for each row in `test`, but not for each value in the *original* `iris` dataframe. My code `range(len(test) / 2) * 2` is two lists [0..149] concatenated together, which can be seen in the output from `test[-10:]` (the original and new indices don't match up).

Comment: `test` (length 300) is twice as long as the original `iris` (length 150); the first 150 rows in test only contain the values for `SepalLength`, and the next 150 only contain values for `SepalWidth`. So I made an index that goes from [0..149] twice. Does that make sense?